# php mysql search by variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with how can I retrieve data from mysql having a variable in
my sql query.. my php code is

```
$status=$_GET['status'];
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE status='$status' ";
```

When I run the query mysql generates

```
 unknown column 'Lead'
```

where Lead is the value of $status. I tried it with 
\'$status\' , '{$status}' but same error..
Please help me I'm working on it since yesterday but found no solution.
I tried mysql_real_escape_string() but same error.. may be I was using it with wrong syntax.

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE status=".mysql_real_escape_string($status);
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: If you echo($query) what do you see?

Comment: `$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE \`status\`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($status) . "'";`

Comment: Keep in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php (I recommend placeholders in general to avoid having to worry about quotes - I'm lazy.)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have "where $status='$status'"?  Those pesky symbols like to jump around sometimes.

Comment: @NullUserException that was an answer, you should've typed it as such!

Comment: You should look into using PDO

Comment: @davesnitty when I echo output is SELECT * FROM students WHERE status=Lead

Comment: @NullUserException thanks bro!! It worked.... post it as answer

Comment: @Sikander What will happen when the `$_GET` variable = `';drop table students;'`?

Comment: @iight  what a point!!! but how can I avoid it??

Comment: Read and lookup people's (@NullUserException, Lajos, etc.) suggestions for `mysql_real_escape_strings` or `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$status=$_GET['status'];
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE status='".$status."'";
```

and escaping is a good idea, but I think mysql_escape_string is deprecated and its usage is discouraged, you should always use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid 'status' is a reserved word for sql: see http://drupal.org/node/141051

Try:

$status = mysql_real_escape_string($status)

$query  = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `status` = '$status'";